# Snowflake concatenate Name's based on Start Time

Tags: concatenation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm attempting to concatenate names from the Name column based on start time found in the Start Time column as found in the following [Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Chns1.png).

The end result should concatenate the name from rows 1 (Holiday Sale) and 2 (New Year) because the Start Time's fall on the same date and time. So it should read similar to "Holiday Sale, New Year" with the Start Date column showing "2019-12-26 00:00:00".

I've tried to alter several queries that were originally used to merge dates based on a name or ID so that they would merge (concatenate) names based on the dates. None of these proved successful and resulted in a "Timeout Error". Here's a couple of queries I've attempted:
- [start date end date combine rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36007852/start-date-end-date-combine-rows?newreg=21d5bdea9b3948a99ffd029a4d0e1032)
- [Merge overlapping date intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561130/merge-overlapping-date-intervals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe LISTAGG https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html is something you are looking for.
Try

```
select listagg(name, ', '), start_time from table group by start_time;
```

Comment: Yes that works! Additionally, would the code be similar if I was trying to have it be concatenated base on both the start time and the end time? For example, if I was trying to display the end result as a column chart. I would need the x-axis as the date range and the y-axis would show me which names (promotions) appeared on each day and when those promotions stopped.

Comment: So I figured this second portion out by performing an inner join on a base date table.

select .bd.date, listagg(name, ', ') as "NAME"
from base_date bd
inner join table t on t."START" <= bd.date AND t."END" >= bd.date
group by 1
order by bd.date